# DrawerLayout lock mode doesnt work as expected

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

My code below locks the drawerlayout when using a tablet (in landscape mode)

```
if(condition)
{
    //Landscape mode
    mDrawerLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeLockedOpen);
    mDrawerLayout.SetScrimColor(Color.Transparent);
}
else
{
    //Portrait mode
    mDrawerLayout.SetDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked);
    mDrawerLayout.SetScrimColor(Color.LightGray);
}
```

However, if I open it up in landscape it locks the drawerlayout as expected, however when changing it to portrait mode I cannot swipe it away.  It does the opposite when opening it up in portrait (allows me to open and close) but then changing to landscape it opens it but doesn't lock it in so the user can swipe it away and break the view.

Not to sure what I am missing, as I have stepped through the code countless times and it follows the right paths.

Comment: does it execute the mentioned code on each orientation change?

Comment: @MehulJoisar yes it does.

Comment: What's `condition`? How and where is that set?

Comment: @Krumelur it's `((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)mFrameLayout.LayoutParameters).LeftMargin >= 180`

Comment: Have you debugged? Is it TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: When its in landscape it is true, when it is in portrait it is false.

Comment: I had same issue. As my test results in a previously created and destroyed activity's onCreate method it does not works as expected. I solve problem with locking and unlocking layout in all fragments onActivityCreated method which can be accessed from menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue and moving that code to my onResume() did the trick.

Comment: I know this was asked ages ago.  But finally got to change it, and it works 100%.

Comment: Awesome. You saved hours of my debugging. Thank you Johan for asking this question and thank you armandooj for the answer.